# Mongoose find returns no result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a Node JS application that uses Mongoose and when I run GET, mongoose wasn't able to return results.

This is my code:

routes/api.js (some of the commented out portion are for MongoClient, which works for me)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router(); //HTTP requests
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; //MongoClient object.  No need to setup models for mongoose.
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_CREDENTIALS);

var Users = require('./models/user');
var config = require('./config');

// Connect
// const connection = (closure) => {
//     return MongoClient.connect(config.database_credentials, (err, db) => {
//         if (err) return console.log(err);

//         closure(db);
//     });
// };

const sendError = (err, res) => {
    response.status = 501;
    response.message = typeof err == 'object' ? err.message : err;
    res.status(501).json(response);
};

// Response handling
let response = {
    status: 200,
    data: [],
    message: null
};


//HTTP GET
// Get users
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    // connection((db) => {
    //     db.collection('users')
    //         .find()
    //         .toArray()
    //         .then((users) => {
    //             //response.data = users;
    //             res.json(users);
    //         })
    //         .catch((err) => {
    //             sendError(err, res);
    //         });
    // });
    console.log(process.env.DATABASE_CREDENTIALS);
        User.find(function(err, users) {
            if (err)
                sendError(err);

            res.json(users);
        });
});
```

routes/models/user.js

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

My MongoDb is hosted on Mlab. When using MongoClient, I can get it to work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Specifically : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client which clearly demonstrates returning the promise and resolving with `.then()`, which should happen **before** you have an `app.listen()` or similar in your code.

Comment: I have already placed the mongoose connect code before app.listen and placed a variable with require. But I still can't get it to work.

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_CREDENTIALS, {useMongoClient : true});
    const api = require('./routes/api'); // folder where routes file are stored